# Function that gives negative integral

Tags: calculus

Is there any function $h(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with conditions such that $h(0) = 0$ and $h(2\pi) = 0$ such that the following integral

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} (h')^2 - h^2 \: dx
$$
is negative?

Comment: **Hint:** The fact that the two points are $0$ and $2\pi$ strongly suggests using trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) the given integral is non-negative when $\int_0^{2\pi}h(x) dx=0$. It can be negative otherwise. Take for example $h(x)=\sin(x/2)$: $h(0) =h(2\pi) = 0$ and
$$\int_0^{2\pi} ((h')^2(x) - h^2(x))\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{\cos^2(x/2)}{4}-\sin^2(x/2)\right)dx=\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}-1\right)=-\frac{3\pi}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you also explain, is there any example for the upper bound being $\pi/2$?

Comment: I did not get your question...

Comment: I mean is there any function that gives us the negative integral, but with an upper bound being not 2$\pi$, but $\pi$/2?

Comment: No, it does not exists. See the following link for $a=\pi/2$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions#Second_version